# JavaScript numbers only script (without blocking keyboard shortcuts)

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have a script in a web application of mine which forces users to type only numbers into certain text fields. However, when the appropriate text field is selected, the script blocks ANY keyboard input other than number keys and tab. I don't want to limit the user from being able to use their browser's or my app's keyboard shortcuts just because they are typing in a numerical field. (Also, I'd rather not just validate the field instead of preventing number input, my app updates the page based on the numerical input live, so it wouldn't be as nice.)

Can someone please help write/find a little script for me? A simple variation of these numbers-only scripts that can be overrided when a modifier key is pressed is enough (and I guess the overrided character would have to be deleted, too).

Comment: use onchange, and if(isNaN(value))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to write a script for you, but I'll give you some pseudo-pseudo-code:

```
input = input.replace(/\D/, '');
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work for some reason. It looks like a good idea though.

Comment: Here it is, I'm learning JavaScript so sorry if this just turns out to be a stupid error: onChange="this.value=this.replace(/\D\,'')" Also, onChange doesn't fire until the text field loses focus, but nothing happens anyway and I still can have letters in the field.

Comment: @the It needs to be more along the lines of `<input onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, '')">`. You may have to refine it a bit with code from other answers regarding Ctrl keys and such, but this hopefully gives you the right idea. Look into [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) though.

Answer (score 0):

Try YAV, Javascript validator library.
I think you need mask feature.
Look at field `Custom:` from this example

- http://yav.sourceforge.net/en/example_7.html

Comment: This looks nice, but I still can't use my browser's keyboard shortcuts while typing in the custom text field. Can I allow this through more advanced masks in this library?